# Returning full list of navigation properties via JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, navigation-properties

I am working with returning data to a Web API and would like to have a complete list of navigation properties returned, as well. I recognize that this involves using the `.Include()` directive, however, it's not working the way it seems to be described in the MS documents for loading related entities.

```
    public S3Roles GetRoleById(Guid roleId)
    {
        using (_context)
        {
            try
            {
                return _context.S3Roles
                    .Include(r => r.S3UserRoles)
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == roleId);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this example in "real life", I end up with a single `S3UserRole` record coming back, instead of the five that actually exist in the database.

Oh, but it gets weird from there. I can look at the record in the Chrome Rest Web Service Client and retrieve the record with the single S3UserRole along with it. If I switch over to Fiddler and execute the same GET request, it returns a 504 error `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 655 bytes.`

How can I properly return all of the navigation property records in a manner that will `automagically` and properly get serialized to JSON to be returned to the controller of the Web API and, ultimately, to the caller?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but what creates the `_context`?  It looks like you are `using` a `_context` that was previously created somewhere else, but that `using` statement will dispose it at the end of the method.  If something calls that method a second time on the same instance, it will be already disposed, unless something else recreates it first.  This is a weird pattern.  If you're going to dispose the context in the method, shouldn't you also be creating it there?  `using (DbContext _context = new DbContext()) { ... }`

Comment: @BrianRogers my `_context` is part of the constructor for the repository allowing it to use the Dependency Injection model preferred by EF Core. I'm hoping it's not an issue with the context being closed/disposed, as that pretty much defeats any point of using DI.

Comment: So the context is owned/created by something outside the repository's control.  I would argue that it's not the responsibility of the repository to dispose it then.  What happens if you remove the `using` statement?  (According to [this](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U9efX_ldXpo), it should be OK not to explicitly dispose an EF context, if you're worried.)

Comment: @BrianRogers well...that wasn't it. I pulled it out of the `using` and still only received one of five expected S3UserRoles. My understanding is the `FirstOrDefault` applies to the first entity described, in my case the S3Roles. I may try "the long way" and select into a new S3Role, which seems counter-intuitive, but, hey...stranger things, right?

Comment: OK, thanks for following up even though it turned out to be a blind alley.